# Unable to create session using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

To test whether Hibernate session factory is working fine or not, I tried using the following code.

```
public class HibernateUtilities {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    ......
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session = ....
        session.beginTransaction();

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

    }

}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" Problem creating session factory
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.test.HibernateUtilities.main(HibernateUtilities.java:50)
```

My hibernate configuration code is like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration.....>
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        ........
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

What is the reason that I am getting this error.

Comment: You have to learn how to debug. Print the exception stack trace which tells you everything.

Comment: Try catching the **Exception** instead of HibernateException and "printStackTrace()" will help you digging the root cause.

Comment: I question whether you can commit an 'empty' transaction like you are doing.  You may need to do an quick query to hit the database to ensure your session factory is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. The problem was not to create the session factory. The problem was the mapping of Entity with one to one relationship with other entity. After fixing that mapping, it solves totally.